# C formatting tables

Tags: c, escaping

Hey everyone I have a program where I have to print 4 columns and divide them in pairs. I'm trying to use the "\t" escape sequence but it compiles weird. the first two print a couple of spaces instead of the Tab however the other two rpint out with a tab.

This is the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
      printf("%s","Celsius\tFahrenheit\t\tFahrenheit\tCelsius\n");
      printf("%s","===================================================");
      return 0;
    }
```

And this prints out:

```
    Celsius Fahrenheit              Fahrenheit      Celsius
    ===================================================
    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the tab character but instead with it's interpretation (expansion) by the terminal. Try replacing the `'\t'` with actual spaces, does it work?

Comment: Normally tab stops are at every 8:th character, you need to keep that in mind if you do formatting with tabs. It might be a better alternative to use fixed size field widths.

Answer (score 3):

If you count the spaces:

```
Celsius Fahrenheit              Fahrenheit      Celsius
123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678
```

it becomes clear that your terminal has one tab stop every eight spaces and the tab character moves to the next tab stop.

The first one looks like a space because "Celsius" has seven characters.